# Need feedback!! Should enterprise level application can user one user to connect sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, connection

I am working on one large scale application (Web MVC Application), which can be used by enterprise level organizations later on where more than 50 or may be 100s of user are accessing the web at the same time and requesting data eventually to MS SQL Server.

My question is,

"Is it fine to use one user (in terms of connections and to fulfill all user requests) for all database connection by server side data access layer?"

What I mean is that whether there is any limit by MS SQL Server for one user to make number of connections simultaneously or not?

Your feedback will be very useful for me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation on the number of connections per user. Our website does this. All of our code accesses the database with one SQL Server credential.

There is, however, a hard limit on the total number of connections (around 30k) to the instance. We found this out the hard way with hundred of databases and connection pooling from tens of application servers.